# How to find the Interface EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer in spring boot 2.0

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to change bind port when the application running，
But Meet a error message 'EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer cannot be resolved to a type'.
My Spring boot version is 2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.

the following code:

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CustomizationBean implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

@Override
public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
    container.setPort(9000);
}

}
```

thanks a lot

Comment: Things have moved in 2.0.0 to accommodate the support for web flux. However if you only want a different port just use `server.port=9000` and ditch this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SpringApplicationBuilder to set the property server.port programatically. use this inside your spring boot main method.

```
HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put("server.port", 9000);
new SpringApplicationBuilder()            
    .properties(properties)
    .run(args);
```

Comment: what if i want to set random port available?

Comment: Just use server.port=0 (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-user-a-random-unassigned-http-port)

Answer (score 9):

As far as the port is concerned, I'd use the configuration option as already answered.

However, you can still use a customizer, however, the types and location will change in Spring Boot 2.0, see:

```
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CustomizationBean implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory> {

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory server) {
        server.setPort(9000);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

SpringBoot has an easy configuration for binding port, just use **server.port** to set the customized port in application.properties

Comment: thanks a lot, My choice is use SpringApplicationBuilder to set port programatically.